# Bootstrap popover with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a bootstrap popover with a form in it. The (maybe) special case is the onclick event, which caused problems since I was not able to escape single quotes in it. I tried it with several escape sequences (\' - \\' - ") with no success. Only with " the template is rendered fine but still does not work - although I see no error message. The html code (curly braces are coming from smarty):

```
<img src="edit.gif" alt="" data-toggle="popover" date-html="true" data-content="<textarea id='{$SUPPLIER.id}ta'>{$SUPPLIER.comment}</textarea><img src='disc.gif' alt='' onclick=&quot;alert($('{$SUPPLIER.id}ta').val);&quot;>">
```

So my next attempt was to place the popover content in a hidden div and get it with a function, but no popover is shown:

```
//document ready

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html : true,
    content:function() {
        if($(this).data('container')) {
            //loads data from e.g. a hidden div
            var elem = $(this).data('container');
            //alert here shows correct content
            return $(elem).html();
        } else {
            return $(this).data('content');
        }
    }
});

//html
<img src="edit.gif" alt="" title="{get text="Set Comment"}" data-toggle="popover" data-container="#ta_container{$SUPPLIER.id}">
<div id="ta_container{$SUPPLIER.id}" class="hide">
    <textarea id="ta{$SUPPLIER.id}">{$SUPPLIER.comment}</textarea><img src="disc.gif" alt="" onclick="alert($('#ta{$SUPPLIER.orderpart_id}').val);">
</div>
```

Comment: Plugin Bootstrap-Dialog is easy to use and work well : [GitHub link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a snipplet with a working example using Bootstrap-Dialog plugin.

```js
$('.supplier-link').on('click', function(){
  // Get parameter
  var supplierId = $(this).attr('data-supplier-id');
  var supplierComment = $(this).attr('data-supplier-comment');
  // Open Dialog and provide param
  BootstrapDialog.show({
      title: 'Supplier ' + supplierId,
      message: '<textarea>' + supplierComment + '</textarea>',
      data: {
          'supId': supplierId
      },      
      buttons: [
        {
            label: 'Action with supplier',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: function(dialogRef){
                alert('Do somehting with supplier id ' + dialogRef.getData('supId'));
            }
        }
      ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span class="supplier-link" data-supplier-id="Your_Smarty_SupplierIdXX" data-supplier-comment="Your_Smarty_SupplierCommentXX">img of supplier XX</span>
<br>
<span class="supplier-link" data-supplier-id="Your_Smarty_SupplierIdYY" data-supplier-comment="Your_Smarty_SupplierCommentYY">img of supplier YY</span>
```

Comment: Okay, seems to be a good approach. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Nice if that help you! I removed some non-pertinent config